# Are there any image gallery/portfolio CMS systems friendly to both end users and programmers?

Tags: images, photography, cms, gallery

I need an image gallery/CMS tool for a low traffic portfolio. Hosted would be good, self-hosted (PHP) can be fine.

For my usage, I can write PHP/CSS/JS/HTML so it can be sparse-ish, but ideally I'd want something that is hands off.

The actual appearance and the ability to manage photos is really the most important thing, as opposed to cost or hosting.

Comment: Is it required to be in [tag:php]? (Even if it’s hosted?) / What actual features do you need? Many or only one user, public/private galleries, metadata, comments, etc. Your question might be too broad right now.

Comment: If it is a closed hosted application, then it doesn't matter what it is written in. I apologize if that wasn't clear.